# How to convert a cell reference into a string in Google Spreadsheet Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a google apps script function that allows you to extract the string from the reference in a cell?

For instance suppose my cell contains the value:

```
=A1:A5
```

The value that results from this reference will be the value in A1.

What I want to know is whether a function exists to get the string value of the reference; i.e. convert =A1:A5 to "=A1:A5" or more preferably "A1:A5", where "=A1:A5" and "A1:A5" are strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you get cell you can just use .getFormula().

Reference:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range

Comment: I did do quite a bit of research. I'm still new to the script API so I must have missed that function. Luckily, now that this question is posted, other people in the future won't have to look as hard. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I still have no idea how to do it. How did you get the string value of range directly in a cell.